# Web portal taking data from web service or database - architecture pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, n-tier-architecture

I'm working on the project that is currently built upon the following architecture:

1) First solution

- Project that has all the database logic (DAL) based on Entity Framework 5
- WebAPI project responsible to feed data to customer Web Portal and smartphone apps

2) Second solution

- MVC4 project that serves as customer Web Portal

Customer Web Portal and WebAPI are sitting on the same server. WebAPI is directly accessing database, while Customer Web Portal is accessing it over WebAPI. Reason for choosing this architecture is to lower development time as Web Portal and smartphone apps are calling 85% of same web services. However, I'm extremely worried on how good performance architecture this is. I think that Customer Web portal should directly access database and that it would be more efficient way.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What do you mean by directly access database? Do you still want to use your DAL library, and just don't want to use WebAPI, right?

Comment: I basically want Web Portal to user DAL Library directly in the same manner Web API is using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Architecture is always tricky ant it's always a compromise between different factors like speed of development, maintainability, performance, and scalability. So, you need to weigh all pros and cons.

#### Accessing DB via WebAPI

1 . Definitely introduces some overhead in performance. But how much? Let's say that passing your call through additional wrapper (WebAPI) will cost you approximately 2-3 extra milliseconds per call, and around 200MB of extra RAM total. I think, it's not a real issue, but you know better all the details and it's up to you.

2 . That solution can get some benefits from using the Cache. If you configure IIS to cache requests to WebAPI, then both: WebAPI clients and portal will increase the performance.

#### Accessing DB via DAL directly

1 . Theoretically, you're introducing two entry points to your DB you need to take care of. What if you need to add some logic, which must be used by WebAPI client and your portal, and that logic is web-specific (e.g., something related to user sessions)? You shouldn't add it to DAL, instead you need to add another layer with another library, which will be used by both: WebAPI and your portal. And if your only access point is the WebAPI, then you can modify just the WebAPI to get the result.

#### To summarize:

Those are just some pros and cons. But if your project is not huge, if it's not planning to be on a very high load, then the only factor which I would consider is the cost of development. If it's faster to use WebAPI as a single entry point, then just go with it.

Comment: I'm mostly worried about IIS threads on WebAPI side. Let's say 10.000 users are accessing the portal, each will get available IIS thread to handle the requests. What will happen to WebAPI in that case, will it be able to serve multiple requests coming from Web Portal that fast considering it will have to use some IIS threads for smartphone apps as well.

Comment: IIS creates a separate thread for every request. But the limiting factor here is the number of concurrent requests. If you have 10,000 hits/hour, then you'll have roughly just 3 concurrent reqs/sec (and 3 threads accordingly). But let's say you have an overwhelming number of requests. Then yes, your WebAPI will not be able to handle all the clients' and portal's requests. For IIS clients and portal are equal and they will receive deny responses equally. If portal is more important, you can create another WebAPI instance on the same IIS and route client and portal request to different instances

Comment: And don't forget about cache. If it's appropriate in your situation it can greatly cover you